# How to debug runtime error in Visual Studio such as "Could not find file .exe"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, debugging, runtime-error

I recently created a new project using Visual Studio 2022 in "console app". My previous projects don't have this type of error and they debug just fine. I haven't changed any setting or files as well. Actually, I am trying to make an array and declare some return value functions.

[image: compiler error].png

Comment: That most likely means your code failed to build. Did you check the error list?

Comment: @UnholySheep I see, thanks. There are 2 errors, I tried to fix it but now I have 4 instead of 2. :')

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No one can possibly help you fix the errors without seeing your [mcve]

Comment: I can give you some advice however. Please try to understand what the compiler is telling you with the error message. Many new people here see an error message and instead of trying to understand what the error is about they randomly change lines in their code. If that is the method you used its not a good path to solving the problem.

Comment: Will the problem occur after creating  a new C++ project? Try to repair  Visual Studio or reset settings.